# How to share methods between ruby modules

Tags: ruby, module

Here is what I tried:

```
module A
  def self.method1; "method1"; end
  def method2; "method2"; end
end

module B; include A; end

B.method1  # => error
B.method2  # => error
B::method1 # => error
B::method2 # => error
```

I want to avoid copying and pasting equivalent code between two modules. The reason I'm using modules instead of classes here is because I don't need more than one instance of each module, as they simply hold constants (other modules, at this point).

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you only want one instance of this code why not use a singleton?

Comment: Mainly because I'm not aware of the advantages and disadvantages of that solution. Some go as far as to say they are evil, while others seem to think they're ok. What do you think?

Comment: When used correctly they can be helpful, I am not sure of your use case though so I cant say for sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plain `include` only gives you instance methods (`method2` in your particular piece of code). If you want to share module-level methods - extract them to separate module and `extend` other modules with it:

```
module A
  extend self     # to be able to use A.method1

  def method1
    "method1"
  end
end

module B
  extend A
end

B.method1       # => "method1"
```

It is also possible get module-level methods by `include`, but with a little twist, using hook method:

```
module A
  def self.included(other)
    other.extend ModuleMethods    # this is where the magic happens
  end

  def instance_method
    'instance method'
  end

  module ModuleMethods
    def module_method
      'module method'
    end
  end

  extend ModuleMethods     # to be able to use A.module_method
end


module B
  include A
end

B.module_method        #=> "module method"
B.instance_methods     #=> [:instance_method]
```

Comment: Note that this won't give you A.method1 - if you want that, one option would be to call "extend self" inside A.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note that `A.method2` won't work either. You can create objects including `A` (or `B`) that will have `method2`:

```
class C
  include B    # (or A)
end
c = C.new
c.method2
```

So, for `method2` it just works as you intended.

Regarding `method1`, it is a singleton method of the object `A` and there is no way to inherit it.